# Why can't I make a 12 V 10 A transformerless power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I have looked at many transformerless power supplies (TPS) but I have not found a reasonable explanation as to why we cannot make a 12 V 10 A output transformerless power supply, or any explanation as to why this is not possible.

Can someone explain? (I am not an electronics engineer, just a hobbyist.)

Comment: who says you can't? It's going to take a fortune worth of poly caps, but it's certainly possible. finding a constant 12v 10a load for it might be harder, most useful 12v things present a varying load to the source. It's like the question: "can i jump start a car with 9v batteries?"; yes, but nobody in their right mind would want to because of the impractical feasibility.

Comment: What would be the input to your power supply? And what would be the output load? It makes a difference how to answer your question. It might be possible, but nobody does it if it makes no sense to do it if cheaper and smaller and better options are available.

Comment: Are you talking about a transformerless power supply fed from mains AC? Are you only excluding transformers, with inductors permitted, or are all magnetic devices forbidden? Transformerless means no isolation from mains, what sort of application do you foresee where that would be safe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You tell us, why can't you?

Answer (score 5):

As others have stated it's hard to answer but I'll put this answer for the following assumptions:

- You want to make a capacitive dropper
- The output current will not be constant (i.e. constant voltage output)

If not true, please tell so I can delete or modify this answer.

---

You are not an engineer so I'll keep the explanation as simple as possible.

This is a simplified schematic of a typical capacitive dropper:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2AGAp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, here is how it works:

The capacitor CX has a frequency-dependent reactance so it can be used a dropper resistance. The input current due to the load drops voltage across the CX due to its reactance. The remaining voltage will then be rectified by the bridge, and the ripple will be filtered out by CF1, so you'll have a DC voltage.

Here some additions:

- The CX acts as a dropper, so as the load current changes the voltage across the capacitor will change as well: The lower the load current, the less the voltage drop.
- You'll need a regulator (U1) because the voltage drop changes with load current i.e. for varying loads the output voltage needs to be stabilised. If the load current will always be the same you may not need a regulator.
- The RS is required to limit the inrush current: There will be a large inrush current due to CF1 during start up, and it needs to be limited with a series resistance, RS.

Now, for a 12 V / 10 A output:

- U1's input voltage should be at least 14-15 VDC (an optimistic assumption). This will bring a loss of **at least** 30 W (i.e. (15-12) x 10) at full load. This is a huge loss so requires **serious thermal design** (i.e. huge heatsinks, fans, etc).
- For 10A DC output current CF2 should be very large (e.g. 10000 uF or higher). Can be a combination of different capacitors, shouldn't be a problem.
- For 10A DC output current CF1 should be relatively high (e.g. 1000 uF or higher).
- At light loads or no load there's going to be no drop across CX so the full line voltage will appear across the input of the bridge. This means that the CF1's voltage rating should be at least 400 VDC. Combining with the statement above, can be achieved by parallel combination of smaller capacitors (e.g. 4 x 220 uF/400V electrolytic capacitor). Shouldn't be a problem.
- Since the voltage across CF1 can be higher than 300 VDC, the regulator design should be made for 350-400V and this requires high voltage high current transistors. This can be done by paralleling transistors but, combining with the thermal design, **size will be large**.
- To decrease the voltage stress of the regulator and CF1 and therefore to make them *smaller* a dummy load can be placed across either CF1 or CF2, or even both *(I put one across CF2, output)* so that a non-zero input current flows **regardless of no, light or full load operation** and drops some voltage across CX. This will decrease the voltage across CF1, so it won't have to be rated for 400V, and the regulator won't have to be designed for 350V but to make the voltage levels reasonable the dummy load should draw a significant amount of current. Therefore this will bring **unnecessary extra loss**, as well as a few more serious considerations about thermal design. Either way you can't get away from huge heatsinks.
- Since CF1 will be very large, the reactive currents will be high therefore the input RMS current will be ridiculously high (Expect at least 5 A). A note here: Placing a dummy load decreases the voltage stress of CF1 but it doesn't have any effect on the value of CF1 so its capacitance, therefore the reactive currents, will still be high regardless of dummy load presence. And the total RMS currents will increase in case of a dummy load presence.
- This high current will cause an excessive dissipation across the inrush limiter resistor, RS.
- Obviously, CX will be very large (i.e. a few hundred microfarads like 220 uF or higher). The capacitor should be suitable for series connection, and voltage rating should be at least 275 Vac. Reasonable size capacitors are in range 1u - 2.2u so CX can be built by paralleling 100 of these, but **size will be very large**.

> as to why this is not possible

It's not impossible. It's impractical. From the explanation above,

- Assuming the input RMS currents will be 5A, the apparent input power will be 1 kVA which is way too high for 120 W useful power.
- Size will be ridiculously large due to capacitors, transistors, bridge and heatsinks.
- Requires excessive thermal design which brings audible noise and excessive weight.

Comment: Excellent answer, with a few tweaks perhaps. Voltage across CF1 cannot (can, but not practically) be allowed to rise to 100s of volts, a clamp across CF1 or CF2 can consume all the current needed on no load, generating lots of heat, but allowing 25 V parts there. You're being too pessimistic about CX construction, motor-run capacitors are not expensive, rated for the voltage, and sizes of 50 uF are common.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks. You are right about that CX can be built with motor caps. Combining 5-6 cylindrical caps instead of 100 box type MKPs is much easier, yes, but my concern was the size actually because either way the total volume will be around 1000 cm³. And for the voltage across CF1, I forgot to mention dummy load and its purpose - I put it into schematic but didn't mention anything about it. Thanks again.

Comment: A critical problem with this approach is that the voltage drop across CX decreases with decreasing load currents.  That is, at 1 A load the voltage across CF1 will be 9 times higher than at 10 A load because the voltage drop across CX will be 9 times less.  This probably eliminates all IC regulators for use as U1.  Note that the mains voltage in NZ (240 V, 50 Hz) is the worst possible input for this type of circuit.

Comment: CX and CF1 form a two-impedance voltage divider.  Once you determine the maximum allowed input voltage for U1, you can solve for the two capacitor values at 0.1 A and 10 A.  Hint: this will not go well.

Comment: @AnalogKid thanks, those concerns/problems are already stated in my answer (4th and 5th items).

Comment: Really great answers. Now i can see im not going make this from parts in my rummage box. And the component cost, if i purchased, would be more than a safer design using a transformer.
So this is why i'm not seeing these projects on the internet. 
Anyone have any good ideas for driving a 12V DC 30amp motor without buying an expensive power supply?